# Return nothing or Error 500 when posting JSON by Python requests?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, http-status-code-500, http-status-code-415

I have a crawl-data task, after inspecting the URL with Firefox F12 (DevTools), I find that the site needs a JSON array input looks like:

> **phyIDs**: Array
>   **0**: **"FDER047ERDF"**

and returns some data also in JSON format:

> **trueIDs**: Array
>   **0**: **"802.112.1"**

What I need is just the 'trueIDs', so I use Python 3.6.1 and Requests to do the job, here is parts of the code:

```
import json
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0',
           'Cookie': 'JSFDKF.......',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}

data = {'phyIDs': json.dumps([{0: 'FDER047ERDF'}])}

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False,
                     data=data)
print(resp.text)
```

But the printed response text is a html like message saying that some error occurs, and the status_code is **500**, however, if I comment the 'Content-Type' part in headers, and use normal **dict** instead of JSON as the input data, then nothing returns and the status_code changes to **415**, now I don't know what to do and hope someone could help me, thanks very much!

...........

Thanks guys, I have solved this. The problem is that I shouldn't add '0' in the JSON array!

Comment: Aren't you passing a dictionary in your example code?

Comment: @AlexWeavers Sorry, I don't know your meaning.

Comment: Read about [more-complicated-post-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: i am not understand what the post request,which you post successfully.In your browser

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read that part and change the parameter to json=data, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, i could not upload the screen shot, briefly speaking, I have tried to include all of the contents in headers and do exactly the same as the browser, but still get the http 500 return.